# datatype mismatch in criteria expression in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, cascadingdropdown

I am creating form in access in which i have to implement cascading combo boxes , data in lower combo box is dependent on its parent value selected by user. Here is form [image]

on left side is structure of the table and on right side is form. Problem is I am getting error of data type mismatch , unable to understand why this is happening. In the afterupdate event of Diametre of Drill I am populating cutting speed . Whenever I press drop down of Cutting Speed "Datatype mismatch in criteria expression" occurs. Here is code of **afterupdate event of Diametre of Drill**

```
Private Sub cboDiameterDrilling_AfterUpdate()
cboCuttingSpeedDrilling.RowSource = "Select DISTINCT tblDrilling.cuttingSpeed " & _
"FROM tblDrilling " & _
`"WHERE tblDrilling.materials = '" & cboMaterialDrilling.Value & "' AND tblDrilling.diaOfDrill = '` `cboDiameterDrilling.Value ' " & _`
"ORDER BY tblDrilling.cuttingSpeed;"

End Sub
```

I think problem is in WHERE Clause . Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've surrounded the reference to the object's value (cboDiameterDrilling.Value ) in single quotes.

```
 AND tblDrilling.diaOfDrill = ' & cboDiameterDrilling.Value & "'"
```

Solution : `AND tblDrilling.diaOfDrill = " & cboDiameterDrilling.Value & " " & _`

Comment: yes because it is numeric value. I have replace it with your code not working.

Comment: Yes you were right I need to put it in double quotes. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a ". Try:

```
Private Sub cboDiameterDrilling_AfterUpdate()
cboCuttingSpeedDrilling.RowSource = "Select DISTINCT tblDrilling.cuttingSpeed " & _
"FROM tblDrilling " & _
`"WHERE tblDrilling.materials = '" & cboMaterialDrilling.Value & "' AND tblDrilling.diaOfDrill = '" & cboDiameterDrilling.Value & "' " & _
"ORDER BY tblDrilling.cuttingSpeed;"

End Sub
```

Comment: PowerUser, I think that the OP is quoting numeric values.

Comment: @PowerUser still having same issue.

Comment: @Remou yes it is numeric value but why it is giving datatype mismatch.

Comment: Because you have put it in quotes. It should be `"WHERE tblDrilling.materials = " & cboMaterialDrilling.Value & " AND`

Comment: Left end of AND is working fine , issue is with right side tblDrilling.diaOfDrill .